# jquery tablesorter: addParser does not sort properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have created a table and sorted it with tablesorter. One of the columns is a mix of letters and numbers (chr1, chr2, ..., chr10, ... , chrM). I want this column to be sorted as if it were only numbers (from 1 to 22 and then X, Y and M in this order).
I have created my own parser and it works but just for some rows. Then, I find another block of rows which are correctly sorted followed by some other blocks. I do not know why this blocks are formed.

The code is [here](http://invrppr.uab.cat/invdb/prova.php). Maybe with a smaller table it would work properly, because of that I have shown a big one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this parser ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/377/))

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'chrom',
    is: function (s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        // format your data for normalization 
        return s.toLowerCase()
            .replace('chr', '')
            .replace('x', '97')
            .replace('y', '98')
            .replace('m', '99');
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Comment: Thanks! First I have changed my code but I have kept the letters in capitals (X,Y,M), and I have got exactly the same result. Then I have tried with lowercase and it works!! I do not understand why...

Comment: You need to replace them as lower case because of `s.toLowerCase()`. Otherwise you can change the replace function to include a case insensitive flag: `.replace(/X/i, '97');` but this would make it harder to read if you're not familiar with regex.